# Play Framework Checkbox Form and JPA Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, checkbox, playframework

I have an issue related with my ManyToMany  relation. The issue happens when I submit the FORM, my controller saves not only on the JOIN table the mapping, also create a new entry for Type class.

**My Code:**

**VIEW:**

```
@main("Create Form"){


    <h1 class="page-header">New Products Form</h1> 
    <div class="row placeholders div-table">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 div-table-row">
            @helper.form(routes.Products.createProducts){
                <div class="form-group">
                @helper.inputText(form("name"), '_label->"Product Name", 'id->"productName", 'name->"productName", 'class ->"form-control", 'placeholder ->"Enter ProductName") 
                </div><!--End First Form Group-->

                <div class="form-group">

                @for(type <- types) {
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name='@(form("types").name)' id="@type" value="@type">
                        @type
                    </label>
                </div>
                }
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                }
```

**Model:
Product Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Product{

    // Class Attributes
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    public Long id;
    public String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)

    public List<Type> types;

public Product save() {
        JPA.em().persist(this);
        return this;
    }

}
```

**Type Model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Types")
public class Type{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "TYPE_ID")
    public Long id;
    public String description;


    public Type(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Type(){

    } 
    public Type save() {
        JPA.em().persist(this);
        return this;
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
  @Transactional
    public static Promise<Result> createProduct() {
        return Promise.promise(new Function0<Result>() {
            @Override
            public Result apply() throws Throwable {
                Form<Product> productFormModel = Form.form(Product.class)
                        .bindFromRequest();
                if (productFormModel.hasErrors()) {
                    if (request().accepts(MimeTypes.HTML)) {
                        return badRequest(views.html.products.createForm.render(
                                prouctFormModel, Type.findAll()));
                    } else {
                        return badRequest(productFormModel.errorsAsJson());
                    }
                } else {
                    final Product product = productFormModel.get();
                    if (product != null) {
                        JPA.withTransaction(new Function0<Product>() {
                            @Override
                            public Product apply() throws Throwable {
                                List<Type> types = new ArrayList<Type>();
                                for (Type type : product.types) {
                                    if (type.id != null)
                                        types.add(Type.getType(type.id));
                                }
                                product.types = types;
                                return product.save();
                            }
                        });

                        if (request().accepts(MimeTypes.HTML)) {
                            return redirect(routes.Products
                                    .productDetails(product.id));
                        } else {
                            return ok(Json.toJson(product));
                        }
                    } else {
                        return internalServerError();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to declare your @ManyToMany association with jpa annotations expliciting your association like this :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "relation_product_type",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "type_id", referencedColumnName = "TYPE_ID")})
```

It will create a table in base just for this relation.

you should have a look at cascade property defined in @ManyToMany annotation (for avoiding the case you want to delete a product and you delete the product and its type) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/toplink-jpa-annotations-096251.html

Comment: "also create a new entry for Type class" seems a problem of JPA association definition. Your CascadeType.ALL indicates you are saving or creating a new Type when saving or creating a new Product. Isn't it?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I have the annotation in my Entity but the issue is with the Checkbox. I lose my relation, every time that I send the FORM. What i did is search the entity id that comes with the checkbox. Is any other solution, so I could save the relation with the checkbox?? Thanks & Regards

Comment: I have just seen the problem in your relation. In your controller you should perhaps explicitly do a mapping between your form and the selected types . Before your JPA.withTransaction, just do form().bindFromRequest() to inspect your form.

Comment: I do that explicit mapping, when I search again the Type entity with the ID that comes with the form. Is there another way to do this? Is it possible send the entity with the checkbox, to not have the necessity of search the entity in my controller??

Comment: can you post the complete code of your controller? With the new tested association (your CascadeType.ALL is problematic for me), you should avoid your problem. HTH. See you tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i update with my controller method that creates the Product.

Comment: I tried at home... Worked like a charm (unit test OK). the major difference is I use Ebean with jpa annotations. :-/ The minor difference is I found a mistake in the declaration of my association : referencedColumnName = "id" -> referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_ID". Same for Type

Comment: Did you find another way for save the relationship between product and type from the view? or you need to use the same method of my controller?

Comment: Have you tried to redefine hashCode and equals in Product and Type classes (based on id property only) ? I do not see any other solution.

Comment: I dont understand your idea. Can you provide me some example? Is there always a need to search Type if I want to map it with the Product?

Comment: Ebean defines a play.db.ebean.Model class for persistence (all classes persisted derive from this one). In this class, equals and hashCode are redefined. It helps Ebean for differentiating instances (and when persisted, an instance is merged with a previous one or added depending the result of equals evaluation). In your model, hashCode and Equals are not defined (and Object class' equals and hashCode are used. defined on identity relation. not equality). It could be the same with play.db.jpa.JPA

Comment: oh, I think that i get your point. In my JPA entity model I need to overwrite the hashcode and equals method, so I can tell to JPA this is an object that exist so merge.

Comment: Is it the solution ?!?

Comment: I am not with my PC right now, but when I arrived home I will try